# how to run timertask once in a day only one week?

Tags: java

```
for(Date timerDate1=startDate; timerDate1<=cal3.add(cal3.DATE,7);startDate=cal3.add(cal3.DATE,1)) 
{ 
long period=60*60*1000; 
Timer timer = new Timer(); 
timer.schedule(new MyTask(),timerDate,period);
 cal3.add(cal3.DATE,1); 
}
```

Comment: Wher do you want run "timer task"? On server? If yes please see this: http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/

Comment: actually my requirement is to send alert emials before one week from the particular date to my clients..so i want to send emails alerts onec in a day in that particular week

Comment: thanks for ur suggetion but i dont know spring frame work

Answer (score 0):

Use timer.scheduleAtFixedRate

```
void java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)

scheduleAtFixedRate
public void scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task,
                                long delay,
                                long period)
```

Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-rate execution, beginning after the specified delay. Subsequent executions take place at approximately regular intervals, separated by the specified period. In fixed-rate execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the scheduled execution time of the initial execution. If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), two or more executions will occur in rapid succession to "catch up." In the long run, the frequency of execution will be exactly the reciprocal of the specified period (assuming the system clock underlying Object.wait(long) is accurate).

Fixed-rate execution is appropriate for recurring activities that are sensitive to absolute time, such as ringing a chime every hour on the hour, or running scheduled maintenance every day at a particular time. It is also appropriate for recurring activities where the total time to perform a fixed number of executions is important, such as a countdown timer that ticks once every second for ten seconds. Finally, fixed-rate execution is appropriate for scheduling multiple repeating timer tasks that must remain synchronized with respect to one another.

Parameters: task - task to be scheduled. delay - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed. period - time in milliseconds between successive task executions. Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if delay is negative, or delay + System.currentTimeMillis() is negative. IllegalStateException - if task was already scheduled or cancelled, timer was cancelled, or timer thread terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a for-loop, use a single Timer, and pass your task to one of the `scheduleAtFixedRate` methods of Timer, with a period of `TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)`.

Your task class should be constructed with a starting Date and the class should store that date in a field.  In the class's `run` method, use a Calendar to check whether the current time, minus 7 days, is later than the task's start date, and if it is, call `cancel()` and return immedately.

Comment: thank you and even i tried with timer but getting SMTPSendFailedException

Comment: That is not a problem with your Timer.  That is a problem with either the code that sends the e-mail, or your mail server's configuration.  Or both.